# Generated button's function only works on second click

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I have a function that creates an alert box, fills the title field and message with information (error, success, info...) and then adds a button that gets an onclick function to remove the message alert.

When a message is first generated and you click the button nothing happens, but when you click it a second time it'll close the message and works for all messages created later until the page reloads.

```js
    var container = document.getElementById('modal-container');
    var page = document.getElementById('html');
    var current;

    function createBox(msgtype) {
      var back = document.createElement('span');
      back.className = 'modal-window';
      container.appendChild(back);
      var box = document.createElement('div');
      box.className = 'modal-message-box';
      back.appendChild(box);
      if (msgtype == 'error') {
        var head = document.createElement('span');
        head.className = 'errorheader';
      } else if (msgtype == 'info') {
        var head = document.createElement('span');
        head.className = 'infoheader';
      } else if (msgtype == 'success') {
        var head = document.createElement('span');
        head.className = 'successheader';
      }
      box.appendChild(head);
      var title = document.createElement('h2');
      title.id = 'alert-title';
      title.className = 'alert-title';
      head.appendChild(title);
      var msg = document.createElement('h4');
      msg.id = 'alert-message';
      msg.className = 'alert-message';
      box.appendChild(msg);
      var btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.innerHTML = 'Close';
      btn.onclick = closemsg;
      box.appendChild(btn);
      page.className = 'noscroll';
      current = document.getElementById('modal-window');
    }

    function alertBoxPopup(msgtype, title, msg) {
      createBox(msgtype);
      document.getElementById('alert-title').innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById('alert-message').innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function closemsg() {
      document.getElementById('html').className = '';
      container = document.getElementById('modal-container');
      container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }
```

```css
.modal-container{
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.modal-window{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.modal-message-box{
    background: white;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html id='html'> 
  <body>
    <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container"></div>
    <div class="row"><button onclick="alertBoxPopup('error', 'Uh-Oh!', 'You have screwed up something!')">Error</button> <button onclick="alertBoxPopup('info', 'Information!', 'Did you know? This box is just a bit of information!')">Info</button> <button onclick="alertBoxPopup('success', 'YES!', 'You did it man! You did something good!')">Success</button>
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: your html and javascript code for the button?

Comment: I haven't the slightest clue why, but it works here but doesn't when I'm testing it in my browser, does it matter that all the code is in a js file and not in the html code?

Comment: The name of your browser?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, VSCode, and browser-sync. It doesn't seem to matter if I just open the file from a folder or let browser-sync update.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help @JoseMarques

Answer (score 0):

I was able to actually figure this out on accident.

I realized that I stored the page in a variable, was searching for it and on a whim I decided to put the className change after the removeChild. For whatever reason it works.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('modal-container');
var page = document.getElementById('html');
var current;

function createBox(msgtype, extrabtn, ebname, ebfunc){
    var back = document.createElement('span');
    back.className = 'modal-window';
    container.appendChild(back);
    var box = document.createElement('div');
    box.className = 'modal-message-box';
    back.appendChild(box);
    if(msgtype == 'error'){
        var head = document.createElement('span');
        head.className = 'errorheader';
    }else if(msgtype == 'info'){
        var head = document.createElement('span');
        head.className = 'infoheader';
    }else if(msgtype == 'success'){
        var head = document.createElement('span');
        head.className = 'successheader';
    }
    box.appendChild(head);
    var title = document.createElement('h2');
    title.id = 'alert-title';
    title.className = 'alert-title';
    head.appendChild(title);
    var msg = document.createElement('h4');
    msg.id = 'alert-message';
    msg.className = 'alert-message';
    box.appendChild(msg);
    if(extrabtn){
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className = 'row';
        var xtrbtn = document.createElement('button');
        xtrbtn.innerHTML = ebname;
        xtrbtn.onclick = ebfunc;
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = 'Close';
        btn.onclick = function(){
            closemsg();
        };
        box.appendChild(row);
        row.appendChild(xtrbtn);
        row.appendChild(btn);
    }else{
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = 'Close';
        btn.onclick = function(){
            closemsg();
        };
        box.appendChild(btn);
    }
    page.className = 'noscroll';
    current = document.getElementById('modal-window');
}

function alertBoxPopup(msgtype, title, msg, extrbtn, ebname, ebfunc){
    createBox(msgtype, extrbtn, ebname, ebfunc);
    document.getElementById('alert-title').innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById('alert-message').innerHTML = msg;
}

function closemsg(){
    container = document.getElementById('modal-container');
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    page.className = '';
}
```

```css
.modal-container{
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.modal-window{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.modal-message-box{
    background: white;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html id="html">
  <body>
    <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <button onclick="alertBoxPopup('error', 'Uh-Oh!', 'You have screwed up something!')">Error</button>
      <button onclick="alertBoxPopup('info', 'Information!', 'Did you know? this is just information!')">Info</button>
      <button onclick="alertBoxPopup('success', 'YES!', 'You did it man! You did something good!')">Success</button>
    </div>
  <body>
<html>
```